# order result of query by on of two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
    id_key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    key1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    seq_num1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    key2 INTEGER,
    seq_num2 INTEGER,
    data BLOB NOT NULL
);
```

And I want to select `data` where `key1` or `key2` match,
this is simple:

```
SELECT data 
FROM Foo 
WHERE (key1 = ? OR key2 = ?)
```

but then I want to order results of this query by `seq_num1` or `seq_num2`, depending on what matched in the table's row - `key1` or `key2` respectively.

I think that something like this should work:

```
SELECT data 
FROM Foo 
WHERE (key1 = ? OR key2 = ?) 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN key1 = ? 
            THEN seq_num1 
            ELSE seq_num2 
    END
```

but I'm not sure is this optimal solution? Because of in this query I compare `key1` twice, while it should be enough compare once.

I use sqlite3.

Comment: the OR condotion will be much more costly than the comparison

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you want? I don't use sqlite, but this mysql command seems to be understood by sqlite.

```
select
  data, seq_num1 as seq
from Foo
  where key1 = ?
union
select
  data, seq_num2 as seq
from Foo
  where key2 = ?
order by seq;
```